# php mysql add * to SELECT statement

Tags: php, mysql

How can I make something like this (add something to a SELECT command):

```
 $query = "SELECT a.name,a.surname,b.email,c.phone 
           FROM users as a 
           inner join users_email as b 
           inner join users_phone as c
           WHERE a.id=b.id AND a.id=c.id";

 $query .= "ORDER BY a.surname";  

 $result = mysql_query($query,$con);
```

The result should be:

```
$query = "SELECT a.name,a.surname,b.email,c.phone 
          FROM users as a 
          inner join users_email as b 
          inner join users_phone as c
          WHERE a.id=b.id AND a.id=c.id
          ORDER BY a.name";   

$result = mysql_query($query,$con);
$row=mysql_num_fields($result)
```

...but it gives an error: mysql_num_fields() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp-portable\htdocs\db\file.php on line 32...

Comment: Why does it say `mysql_num_fields()` when you are using `mysql_query` in your code?

Comment: You shouldnt use mysql anymore, try PDO or Mysqli

Comment: My mistake...I edited.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Always give a `space` when you concate your query.

```
 $query = "SELECT a.name,a.surname,b.email,c.phone 
           FROM users as a 
           inner join users_email as b 
           inner join users_telefon as c
           WHERE a.id=b.id AND a.id=c.id ";

 $query .= " ORDER BY a.prenume";
            ^
```

Also have a practice of `mysql_error()`.

```
$result = mysql_query($query,$con) or die(mysql_error());
```

**Note:** [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo), or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Comment: And if I want to do something more dynamic like:                 `$query .= " ORDER BY " . $_GET['orderby'] . ;` ???

Comment: @wwwglro - Yes you can do that. `$query .= " ORDER BY " . $_GET['orderby'];`.

Answer (score 2):

Add space after

```
WHERE a.id=b.id AND a.id=c.id";
```

so it should be:

```
WHERE a.id=b.id AND a.id=c.id ";
```

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
$query = "SELECT a.name,a.surname,b.email,c.phone 
           FROM users as a 
           inner join users_email as b 
           inner join users_telefon as c
           WHERE a.id=b.id AND a.id=c.id";

 $query .= " ORDER BY a.prenume";  

 $result = mysql_query($query,$con);
```

a 'space' is required before Order By

Answer (score 1):

```
$query = "SELECT a.name,a.surname,b.email,c.phone 
          FROM users as a 
          inner join users_email as b ON a.id=b.id
          inner join users_telefon as c ON a.id=c.id
          ORDER BY a.name";
```

Answer (score 0):

It shold be

```
 $query .= " ORDER BY a.prenume order(asc/desc)";
```

insetad of

```
 $query .= "ORDER BY a.prenume";
```

and you need to give space before ORDER BY

Comment: That does not make any sense, mysql defaults to ASC. Furthermore, the error corresponds to something else (mysql_num_fields)

Comment: And I wrote it giving space also....??